# Availability of R-base 3.2.3?

Tags: r

When will R-base for 3.2.3 (wooden-Christmas-tree)  be available in the CRAN ubuntu directories?

When I try using `apt-get update` I get an httpError400.

apt-cache policy r-base-core returns: r-base-core: installed: 3.2.2-1trusty@ 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status Candidate: 3.2.2-1trusty@ Version table: *** 3.2.2-1trusty0 0 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 3.0.2-1ubuntu1 0

Comment: Thanks!  3.2.3-1 there is listed as "active development," rather than as "current stable release."  Does that mean that the Ubuntu version is not yet ready for non-bleeding-edge types?  The windows version of r 3.2.3 has been out for a couple of weeks.  Larry Hunsicker

Answer (score 4):

`r-base` 3.2.3 is already available in [the CRAN Ubuntu repository](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), at least for 14.04:

```
$ wget -qO - https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/Packages.gz | zgrep -F 3.2.3 | head
Version: 3.2.3-1trusty0
Filename: trusty/r-doc-pdf_3.2.3-1trusty0_all.deb
Version: 3.2.3-1trusty0
Filename: trusty/r-base-core_3.2.3-1trusty0_i386.deb
Version: 3.2.3-1trusty0
Filename: trusty/r-base-core_3.2.3-1trusty0_amd64.deb
Version: 3.2.3-1trusty0
Depends: r-base-core (= 3.2.3-1trusty0), r-base-dev (= 3.2.3-1trusty0)
Filename: trusty/r-base-core-dbg_3.2.3-1trusty0_amd64.deb
Version: 3.2.3-1trusty0
```

Comment: It seems that I don't have a CRAN repo in my sources.list file.  I gather that the URL is given above.  But what is the "type" that I put at the front of the line?

Comment: @LarryHunsicker type? I don't see any mention of a type in https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer.  It would be nice if apt-get automatically updated my R when a new version becomes available, But it doesn't at this point.  My problem, evidently, is that I don't have a CRAN repository listed in my /etc/apt/sources.list file.  So while I can download the R-base-3.2.3 files listed above, I can't use apt-get to install the file.  The man page for sources.list says that to add this repo to the apt-get list, one is supposed to state a "type" followed by the URL for the repo.  I'd like to get a correct line to add to my sources.list file to add the CRAN repo.  Thanks.

Comment: The CRAN repo readme (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) gives you the correct line. All you need to do is pick a mirror, a list of which is also linked to.

Comment: I'm having no luck.  I have tried four repos.  None of them work.
case tells me connection refused
Berkeley tells me httpError400

Comment: @LarryHunsicker Edit your question to include the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-cache policy r-base-core`

Comment: The outputs of apt-get update are in the message above.
apt-cache policy r-base-core returns:
r-base-core:
installed:  3.2.2-1trusty@

      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
Candidate:  3.2.2-1trusty@
Version table:
*** 3.2.2-1trusty0 0
     100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
3.0.2-1ubuntu1 0

Comment: @LarryHunsicker you can edit your question. Do that, please.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the comment.  The site won't let me move to chat.  I got most of the response to apt-cache above.  The rest is just:
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Please don't post the output in comments. Edit the damn question.

Comment: My problem is that none of the r-repos listed in the CRAN repo list seem to work when added to the sources.list file.  I have now tried four different ones, using the template from the site that you pointed me to before.  Each gives me a different response when I run sudo apt-get update, but none of them are accepted as a source for files.

Comment: What part of "edit your question" do you not understand?

Comment: The question:  What line do I have to add to my sources.list file so that apt-get will use an R repository to update my R when a new version becomes available.